# How to determine the calling page in user control

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a user control which is in common in two asp.net pages how to find out the parent page i dont want to use the page's title is there any concrete way to determine may be a page's class or any way else

I would like to do this

```
if (this.page == "pagename")
{
     //do this
}
else
{
     //do this
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`this.Page`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.page%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in order to find the current page and use `this.Page.GetType()` if you are expecting class name

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
Page myParentPage = this.Page;
```

In your method.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if (this.Page.GetType().Name.ToLower() == "pagename".Replace(".", "_").ToLower()) 
{ 
   //do this 
} 
else 
{ 
   //do this 
}
```